# Bazel - How to Read a String from An Environment File?

Tags: environment-variables, bazel, starlark

I have several `k8s_object` rules in my project and I supply each of them with the same `cluster` name like this:

```
k8s_object(
  name = "k8s_service",
  kind = "service",
  cluster = "gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-b_cents-ideas",
  template = ":gateway.service.yaml",
)
```

So whenever I want to change the cluster name, I have to change it in many different places.

## Goal

I would prefer to set the cluster name in a `.env` file like this:

```
KUBERNETES_CLUSTER=my-cluster-name
```

and let Bazel automatically pick up this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/skylark/tutorial-sharing-variables.html

Create a .bzl file in which you can declare a variable. Import this bzl file in all BUILD files referencing the variable.